# Error en código basico c++. “mivariable” was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, dev-c++, visual-c++

Pues eso, estoy aprendiendo a programar, y quiero hacer un programa para agregar iva, pero me sale este error, alguien que me ayude a arreglarlo porfa? Estoy muy frustado ya[image: +]

Comment: Agrega tu código como texto por favor

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en Español. por favor pasate por [https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour](el recorrido) para hacer buenas preguntas. Para empezar si quires que te ayudemos tendrás que pegar el código y evitar las imágenes.

Comment: Soy daltónico y no puedo ver el código de tus imagen. De todas maneras esta es una página sobre código, no sobre capturas de pantalla ¿Por qué poner capturas en lugar de código? ¡es más complicado! y no se puede copiapegar el código de una imagen ni hacer búsquedas de texto; por favor: **PON EL CÓDIGO**, **NO IMÁGENES**.

Comment: ¿Y no has probado a intentar entender el mensaje de error? Es bastante descriptivo: _was not declared in this scope_

Comment: Lo siento, es que vi que algunos usuarios subian capturas de pantalla, igualmente, ya logré solucionar el problema ese y logre terminar el programa, solo le agregué la variable IVA y toque algunas cositas.

Answer (score 1):

debes inicializar también tu otra variable:

```
float total=precio+21*precio;
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta! luego de haber estado vario rato buscandole la vuelta pude solucionar mi problema, solo agregué la variable IVA e hice que esa se le sumara al precio, y eso diera el total. ;D